# Do you think this oscillator circuit will work if I build it in real life?

Tags: rf, analog, oscillator, oscillation

[image]

I managed to design this oscillator circuit.  It works in the Multisim simulator. It doesn't want to oscillate in thr simulator if I decrease R6 resistor's value although it should have enough gain, so I think that's because transistor's gain at such high frequencies is very low, right? The calculated frequency should be over 200 MHz.  The simulated frequency is just 135 MHz, but if we consider that transistor's capacitance between collector and emitter is 10 pF, 135 MHz is ok. Does the transistor's capacitance change with temperature (God, please no) or it will be stable?

Do you think this circuit will work if I build it in real life? Unfortunately I don't have an oscilloscpe working on such high frequencies.  The idea is to connect a varacactor parallel to C3 and C4 capacitors to have a VCO.

Edit:
[image]
So I decreased C5 capacitance, changed R2 to 1.3k and increased R6 a little bit, so I have Q point somewhere in the middle. Is it better?
Strangely, the frequency did increase
Edit2:I tried my new design in LT spice and it seems to be working perfectly. But in LT Spice all elements are probably ideal.
[image]

Comment: You should be able to eliminate either C5 or C6, they're both DC blocking capacitors so one of them is redundant.

Comment: The capacitance will change slightly with temperature and, single transistor oscillators are not particularly frequency stable without using a crystal.

Comment: @GodJihyo Why does it mind if I use two capacitors instead of one? But we don't want DC in tank circuit.

Comment: The inductance of 1uF capacitors will be too large at these frequencies and will significantly affect the circuit. The capacitor should be physically small and only needs to be a value of more than a few hundred pF. Overall I wouldn't expect this circuit to work in a reality.

Comment: @KevinWhite Yes, but C5 and C6 are in series with tank circuit, aren't they? So I assume higher the capacitance, less will effect tank circuit's capacitance, because capacitance of two capacitors in series is C1*C2/(C1+C2), so if one cap is 3 pF and the other one is 1u, 1u capacitor won't affect the total capacitance much.

Comment: @PavleHribar It's not DC in the tank circuit you have to worry about, it's the DC getting from the collector back to the base, and you only need one of the capacitors for that. Like Kevin said, I would recommend a lower capacitance which will reduce the affect of the transistor on the tank circuit. Generally you would use as low a value as possible that will still allow reliable oscillation. At 200 MHz you should be probably looking at something in the picoFarads.

Comment: @GodJihyo Thanks, but I don't understand, how would lower capacitance reduce affect of the transistor. In my previous comment to KevinWhite I assumed that C5 and C6 are in series with the tank circuit and as they have a lot larger capacitance then the caps in the tank circuit, their effect on the frequency should be lower by my logic

Comment: @PavleHribar Because the larger the capacitor the lower the impedance and the more the rest of the circuit loads the resonant circuit. If you look at schematics of production RF amplifiers and oscillators rather than the 'educational' circuits you find online, you will rarely see a capacitor in the signal path that is greater than a fraction of a uF.

Also I added a paragraph at the end if my answer below, so take a look at that again.

Comment: @PavleHribar - it is not the capacitance that is an issue it is the parasitic series inductance. A 1uF capacitor will be physically large; physically large capacitors will have both significant series inductance (many nanohenries) as well as significant capacitance to ground (many pF). They will adversely affect your circuit.

Comment: @KevinWhite Does C6 coupling capacitor affect the frequency? I'm afraid that too low value would increase/decrease the frequency.

Comment: @PavleHribar - it will, but as you correctly say if it is much larger than C3 and C4 it will have negligible effect. The actual capacitance in the circuit will be much more than C3,C4 because of parasitic and stray capacitances. They could easily add up to 10 or 20pF.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this circuit in LTSpice, and it did not oscillate. Is see a number of issues with it.

A BC547B is a general purpose amplifier, with a transition frequency (Ft) of around 300 MHz. That is not going to work all that well at 200 MHz. Using a transistor with a much higher Ft, say 10 times the frequency you want, would be better.

The emitter resistor is un-bypassed. That is going to drastically reduce the gain at RF frequencies. Adding a 100 nF bypass cap in the simulation allowed it to oscillate, but it still takes a while to start and is not showing a clean signal.

The bias is probably going to be off from the optimum Q point, for maximum voltage swing it should be at the center of the AC load line. Here is a rough idea of where I suspect it will be, this is with a 1000 ohm load on the output.

[image: transistor bias chart]

So there are a few ideas to start with.

Making a 200 MHz LC oscillator with a single transistor is going to be touchy, I've done it at 100 MHz and they're just not very stable. One option is to make the oscillator at a lower frequency and then use a frequency multiplier. If you're looking at one specific frequency rather than something variable you're better off with a crystal oscillator and multiplier.

Comment: yep, I know Q point in the middle of load line would be the best. I didn't use bypass emitter capacitor because then the gain of the circuit would be too high, and that's not good because i'm afraid it will add harmonics to my desired frequency

Comment: @PavleHribar You’ll have to filter the output of this oscillator anyway. You just start from a better place than having a square wave :)

Answer (score 1):

1. The self resonant frequency can be a problem with some 1uF caps, demanding more expensive film caps. That's a problem.
2. C6 is redundant.
3. Using Parallel resonant LC circuits must have the necessary Q and open loop gain to exceed loop losses of Miller Capacitance and negative feedback attenuation.
4. Some improvements might be to move C6 across Re with a slightly smaller Re to increase AC gain for a gain of 30.
   [image]
5. Parasitic capacitance will increase with a ground plane but is often necessary to reduce loop area EMI emissions.  This can also be improved by reducing capacitance across base and increasing the collector which results in less attenuation or more gain.

Another way is the [Colpitts Oscillator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCCsCmC0CM8QE4B0B2AHAZmczALJNgGyYBM82UEkNUciAUADYiYTzmbsTZgFwIbKjBjxEyQTjpwosJALkCCkmGzwwJSgUx0wTAMYh4ycie4mzIcsqEEMjJGFQkSpde9Px0ywS7F4JgAXG0gSCx5%20QS4eThBYclRIMHR%20SHQBcgywfDk3D1INZB8-egATaAAzAEMAVxZgoytzWxjraKEYBHNYFy5fEnQCZEgud2JneSCAd15hARaF-yY5jkil2PBVzctsiK2DOdNWu0627bnO%20AJBc7tZ5ZMuYUhzRFamACdX95fsN5PTgSHYnJ4A8ydAw-TrrTq6ISaAwAJSeCP2IAREAgKigQmxySYAHMnhdzuF8UwAPK-Z7mAjYP7mbFMAAeJhSJgoJkyXLoMQiAGEguyqBByEMeTxyLyBSBBeQADoAZ3gAFImCpqCpOGoQGppXZOJAAPrwE1gM3ZRQmhyjShgbJ6bCYbTYC3yMDmhBm5pg9Zgw42VDkSRh8TYRitZKpdKZJQ5PIBL07WGcazrI5POGLD7bAAOtLzEP1MUx23ZyEEeRldE0SDlAFkAJYsFjQL4qwUqgBuNRYdWgKsq%20egADtKmPgqgmEA) approach.

[image]

Still yet a better approach uses parallel base resonance but a [differential "more" constant current emitter coupled oscillator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=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) using a negative supply but no conducted RF noise or parastics from supply noise. This is a great advantage.

[image]

Comment: In Colpitts oscillator approach, why did you use 5pF and 47pF + 2.2pF for feedback? I've tried this design already, but was not able to make it oscillate in Multisim. It's weird that my first design didn't work in LT Spice, but the second one (under edit) did, while both of them worked in Multisim.

Comment: That improves 2 variables , attenuation , thus more signal and Miller capacitance sensitivity.  This design is different from yours

Comment: the transistor choice is critical and simulation assumption for Cbc and Cbe affect results greatly. not weird at all

Comment: Can too high gain cause problems? Like if I increase C1 and you suggest and then add bypass capacitor, so the gain will be very very high then. Do you think 100pF is ok for C5 capacitor? The others suggested that this cap should have only a few pF of capacitance, but if capacitance is too low, it will affect my frequency.

Answer (score 0):

> [...]but if we consider that transistor's capacitance between
> collector and emitter is 10 pF, 135 MHz is ok. Does the transistor's
> capacitance change with temperature[...]?

Yes, transistor capacitance is far less stable than a good C0G capacitor. A frequency-stable oscillator starts with an LC resonator of high Q whose reactance dominates those other reactances that couple to the transistor.

Transistor \$C_{BC}\$ is a little smaller, and more stable when \$V_{CB}\$ is greater. So try to maximize this voltage. There is not much you can do about \$C_{BE}\$: at least part of the RF cycle must reach at least 0.6V so that collector current flows.
You can increase \$V_{CB}\$ by eliminating the collector resistor: (circuit on right). In LTspice, this circuit oscillates robustly, but be advised that circuit simulators often give an optimistic picture. You can reduce feedback by increasing the value of C6...the SPICE simulation oscillated  well with C6=27pf rather than 7pf. With C6=27pf, Q2 oscillated with as little as 100 uA DC collector current, in LTspice:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvsICn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

 In general, it is better to choose a transistor whose \$f_T\$ is greater than 3X oscillating frequency: stability is better when such a high-frequency transistor's internal capacitances are a fraction of LC resonating capacitance. In the right-hand circuit, C5 is the capacitor which mostly determines resonating frequency (especially if a higher-\$f_T\$ transistor is chosen).

- Don't try building this on a "breadboard" - parasitics capacitances and inductances are too large.
- C8 is often omitted, to the builder's regret. 1uf is likely too large; for a VHF oscillator, even 10nf is large - it should have very short lead length - preferably **no** leads (SMT). Same goes for C7 - a well-grounded transistor base is required.
- Build with a large-area ground-plane so that inductance is minimized.
- Build it compact to reduce lead lengths. Temperature gradients are to be avoided.

---

Shown below is a 127 MHz VCO oscillator similar to the right-hand circuit. It was used as the VCO in a PLL synthesizer. The inductor is air-wound, self-supporting. This is risky because of microphonics. It is better to use a commercial inductor wound on a polyethylene form. Some include an iron-powder core which makes it tune-able.
A one-turn link winding coupled a little inductor energy for output. A 2N3563 VHF transistor was used.

 You'll see some oscillators like this embedded with wax-like compound. This can help to keep all components at similar temperature, and helps damp microphonic effects.
[image: 127 MHz VCO image]

Comment: Around 30 years ago I built a little FM transmitter that was similar to this circuit. I used surface mount parts and wound the inductor on a toroidal core which made it smaller than the air wound coils most people use, more mechanically stable, and less sensitive to nearby objects due to it's self shielding property. I used RTV to fill the hole and stick it to the board so it was pretty well insulated from microphonics. It was a big improvement over the "wind some magnet wire around a pencil" coils the kits they were selling back then used.